# Custom validations troubles

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I’m using Sys.Mvc to count errors and I have added my own custom validations by jQuery.

```
var validationErrors = Sys.Mvc.FormContext.getValidationForForm(this).validate('submit'); 
var errorsCount = validationErrors.length;
```

And also I have some fields, which will by hide (by using jQuery `.hide();`)

Question: How I can remove errors from Sys.Mvc.FormContext if the required element is hidden and add the error if the element is appearing again?

OR
How I can ignore hidden elements validation errors?

Best regards Paul.

Comment: Personally, I'd recommend switching to the Unobtrusive Validation library. It's a lot easier to use, especially if you use the strongly-typed helpers.

Answer (score 1):

Try to initialize the field even if it is hidden (using jQuery), and insert a temporary value. after submitting the form - you can insert the right value into the hidden fields (in the controller).

Something like this:

```
$("#myField").hide();
$("#myField").val("temporaryValidValue");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solution is simply clever, it works (I use .val() not text())! 
Anybody know how I can flush temporary data from form on client side?

Comment: @Paul What do you mean? to empty the temporary data in jQuery?

Comment: Yep, I need to empty temp data

Comment: @Paul I don't think you can do it before submit,(if you flush them in jquery- so why did you filled them), but you can flush it in the controller